# Appending to list of tuples with dictionary elements from input lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two list like that :

```
my_list = [['can you change departure date to 30th March', '207443006734608218498'], ['can you downgrade to economy class?', '276566920664343421717'], ['book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24', '897058868855606085615']]

ids_list = ['207443006734608218498', '276566920664343421717', '897058868855606085615']
```

I check ids_list of element in my_list that match then i try to append on other list

I try to get like that final list:

```
[
  ('can you change departure date to 30th March',
  {
    'ids': {
      '207443006734608218498': 'True',
      '276566920664343421717': 'False',
      '897058868855606085615': 'False'
    }
  }),
  ('can you downgrade to economy class?',
  {
    'ids': {
      '207443006734608218498': 'False',
      '276566920664343421717': 'True',
      '897058868855606085615': 'False'
    }
  }),
  ('book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24',
  {
    'ids': {
      '207443006734608218498': 'False',
      '276566920664343421717': 'False',
      '897058868855606085615': 'True'
    }
  })
]
```

for that i write simple loop and update tuple of dictionary like that

```
>>> data = {} 
>>> for x in my_list:
...     for y in ids_list:
...             data.update({y: "True"} if x[1]==y  else {y: "False"})
...     print((x[0],{"ids": data}))
... 

('can you change departure date to 30th March', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'True', '276566920664343421717': 'False', '897058868855606085615': 'False'}})
('can you downgrade to economy class?', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'False', '276566920664343421717': 'True', '897058868855606085615': 'False'}})
('book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'False', '276566920664343421717': 'False', '897058868855606085615': 'True'}})
```

but when i appending in list, data dict append with wrong value  when i print that is as ablove then data dict value is correct 
what should i doing wrong?

```
>>> t = []
>>> for x in my_list:
...     for y in ids_list:
...             data.update({y: "True"} if x[1]==y  else {y: "False"})
...     t.append((x[0],{"ids":data}))
... 
>>> t
    [
 ('can you change departure date to 30th March', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'False', '276566920664343421717': 'False', '897058868855606085615': 'True'}}),
 ('can you downgrade to economy class?', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'False', '276566920664343421717': 'False', '897058868855606085615': 'True'}}), 
 ('book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24', {'ids': {'207443006734608218498': 'False', '276566920664343421717': 'False', '897058868855606085615': 'True'}})]
```

Comment: You keep reusing the same `data` reference and modifying it in-place. Only the last modification will be visible throughout the list when you are done.

Comment: @MadPhysicist right!! but how to append correct data dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
data.update({y: "True"} if x[1]==y  else {y: "False"})
```

It updates `data` in-place instead of rebinding the name to a new dictionary object. To get a better understanding, let's look at what really gets put into `t` by "unrolling" you loop:

```
t = [(my_list[0][0], {'ids': data}), (my_list[1][0], {'ids': data}), (my_list[2][0], {'ids': data})]
```

Notice that while the outer dictionary (with `'ids'`) is a distinct object every time, the inner one is always a reference to the same `data` object. Any changes you make to `data` will be visible in every element in the list.

The solution is of course to make a new object in every iteration of the loop. The easiest way I can think of is to turn your inner loop into a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
t = []
for x in my_list:
    data = {id: "True" if x[1] == id  else "False" for id in ids}
    t.append((x[0], {"ids": data}))
```

An additional improvement you can make is unpacking `x` to make the code more legible:

```
t = []
for request, id in my_list:
    data = {x: "True" if id == x  else "False" for x in ids}
    t.append((request, {"ids": data}))
```

Finally, your whole code is simple enough to stick into a one-line list comprehension if you should so choose:

```
t = [(request, {"ids": {x: "True" if id == x  else "False" for x in ids}}) for request, id in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your logic via a list comprehension.

In addition, convert your input `my_list` to a dictionary to improve performance.

```
my_list = [['can you change departure date to 30th March', '207443006734608218498'], ['can you downgrade to economy class?', '276566920664343421717'], ['book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24', '897058868855606085615']]

ids_list = ['207443006734608218498', '276566920664343421717', '897058868855606085615']

my_list_dict = dict(my_list)

res = [(k, {'id': {my_id: my_id == my_list_dict[k] for my_id in ids_list}}) \
       for k, v in my_list_dict.items()]
```

**Result**

```
[('can you change departure date to 30th March',
  {'id': {'207443006734608218498': True,
          '276566920664343421717': False,
          '897058868855606085615': False}}),
 ('can you downgrade to economy class?',
  {'id': {'207443006734608218498': False,
          '276566920664343421717': True,
          '897058868855606085615': False}}),
 ('book flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles on April 17-24',
  {'id': {'207443006734608218498': False,
          '276566920664343421717': False,
          '897058868855606085615': True}})]
```